# PL/SQL comments cause compilation errors?

Tags: oracle, plsql, compiler-errors, comments

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0

I have this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_procedure (
/*-------------------------------------------------
comment
--------------------------------------------------*/
   x in VARCHAR2
) IS
BEGIN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

My colleague wrote me that, when he tried to compile it he had a compilation error.

But that code worked for him:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp_procedure (
/********************************************************
comment
*********************************************************/
    x IN VARCHAR2
) IS
BEGIN
    null;
END;
/
```

Earlier when I used SQL*Plus 11.2.0.3.0 to compile my code it showed no errors.

Also, I checked status via

```
SELECT status
FROM dba_objects 
WHERE object_name = 'TEMP_PROCEDURE'
```

status = Valid.

After getting this note, I tried compiling it in

TOAD 12.1.0.22 and PL/SQL developer 10.0.5.1710.
I got the same result - no compilation errors and the procedure is valid.

Does anyone have any ideas why my comments could have caused compilation to fail but his comments do not?

I guess it was an unsubtle way to change my comment format to his comment format, wrapped in "error" context.

Comment: "My colleague wrote me that, when he tried to compile it he had a complation error." >> Where **exactly** did your colleague tried to compile it? SQL*Plus? SQL Developer? TOAD? Oracle Apex? Which version of that tool did they use?

Comment: The status query needs to use `where object_name = 'TEMP_PROCEDURE'`, not `where object_name = 'temp_procedure'`.

Comment: @Littlefoot
As far as I know we dont use Apex so that was one of tools I used. I expect his an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - yes, you are correct. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

The answer is most likely plain and simple: ***Your colleague used a tool that does not handle comments well***. Some reporting tools do not handle these types of things at all.

Comment: Do you know such tools? I tried 3 of programms we used and all showed no compilation errors.
I never tried to call a procedure directly when making a Fastreport report. But even in that case, it should ignore those comments.

Comment: I have worked with other reporting tools, not Apex though. Yes, it ***SHOULD*** ignore those comments, but it simply won't. Best solution is to give in and just do whatever it wants you to do... Most of the tools, that I had issues with these things, are web based.